# Why does it take so long to serve and draw an uncached aspx page using Raspberry PI 3?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, web-server, ubuntu

Our architect noticed that it takes significantly longer to serve and draw an uncached aspx page using Raspbian/Armv71 and Ubuntu Mate compared with x86_64 and Ubuntu 16.04 Linux.

Why does it take so long to serve and draw an uncached aspx page using Raspberry PI 3 and armv71?

Please correct me if I wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because even the Pi3 with its quad core chip is not as fast as your x86 machine and it likely has far less memory. Your comparing apples and oranges. Why would you think that a $35 Pi could replace a modern server. If your app is complicated enough to need an architect ,the Pi may not be an appropriate choice if performance is a major consideration.

Comment: @Steve Robillard, Thank you for your great comment. Please answer this question if you have the time today.

Answer (score 2):

The Pi3 may have a quad core processor running at 1 GHz, but it is unlikely to be as  fast as a desktop or server machine. There are several reasons for this: limited RAM 1GB, slower clock speed, slower disk access etc.

In short expecting similar performance between the $35 Pi and a desktop x86_64 machine is unrealistic. This is an apples to oranges comparison.

If your application is complex enough to require a dedicated architect the Pi may not be an appropriate choice from a performance perspective. The Pi can do many things but competing with a desktop on an equal footing is not one of them. if it were, given, its price point, the Pi would be replacing PC's in large numbers.

Comment: It's also most likely that pound for pound ARM based processors can't compete with x86 processors, i.e., all else being equal a 2 Ghz x86 core will be noticeably more than twice as fast as a 1 Ghz ARM core.  I believe the x86's consume more energy per cycle though.